# Adding extra tag for C types

Tags: c, gcc, c-preprocessor

This is my problem: I'm using NON standard ANSI **C** (a modified r-tems for ARM that compile with standard GCC) and I want add an extra tag in front of **C** types which maintain the type property and add some "stuff". The final result will be something like this:

```
REL char *p;
```

This is still a pointer to `char` and the compiler must treat like that, but now the `RE`L tag will define that `p` is a RELiable pointer too.

```
HP int a;
```

the same but now the `HP` tag will define this `int` as an HighPerformance `int`.

I have to change/modify the preprocessor? How?

PS:that isn't very important however by the specific of my project I can't use a simple `#define` because `REL` and `HP` tag will attached to a special hardware routine bound directly to the preprocessor. (This is the previously mentioned "stuff").

Comment: You can add preprocessor definitions with #define

Comment: `#define REL` will just remove the `REL` for compiling.

Comment: Could you specify how your tags shall be translated? E.g. what should the compiler see instead of `REL char* p;`?

Comment: yeah the complier will see that all REL/HP variables will be treated with reliable/high performance hardware routine attached to the preprocessor (i haven't this routine because they are under copyright).
e.g., all REL variables will be stored starting to address 0x00002000 (a reliable partition of the memory)
e.g., all HP variables  will be stored starting to address 0x00005000 (a high performance partition of the memory)

Comment: I don't see what you mean by "special hardware routine attached to the preprocessor".

Comment: BTW, tag in C has a fixed meaning, relating to the names that are attached to `struct`, `union` and `enum` declarations. Your thing more resembles special "storage class specifiers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`__attribute__((section("SECTION")))`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html#index-g_t_0040code_007bsection_007d-variable-attribute-2622) attribute to tell GCC to place the variable in a specific section.  Then, use a [linker script](http://www.xgc.com/manuals/gcc-1750-ug/p5node5.html) to ensure that the the appropriate sections get mapped to the appropriate places in memory.  For example:

```
#define REL __attribute__((section("REL")))
#define HP __attribute__((section("HP")))

char *p REL;
int a HP;
```

I'm not super-familiar with linker scripts, so figuring out exactly how to do that is an exercise for the reader.

Comment: thanks for the help, it was useful! But now i've a new problem, how can i use the __attribute__ for local variables?

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to deal with such situations are `#pragma` directives. Some compilers such as gcc follow their own lines of syntax by adding `__attribute__`.

Both have come a bit closer since C99 which introduced the `_Pragma` operator. Basically the `_Pragma` operator lets you place `#pragma` directives inside macros and also lets you compose the contents of the directive by usually macro expansion.

So you could have something like

```
#define REL _PRAGMA(do something clever to reserve an special address for __LINE__)
```

or with `gcc` specialities

```
#define REL __((whatever,__COUNT__))
```